# Why would rsync be limiting syncs to ~252Kilobytes?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, rsync

Here's a head scratcher for you... or at least it is for me.

I am transferring a Wordpress site away from WP Engine to an Amazon instance.

I am trying to upload the original Wordpress files from my local Arch Linux computer to the Debian 8.5 Amazon Instance by running:

```
rsync -avz --delete --exclude somefolder -e "ssh -i /home/username/secretkey.pem" /home/username/backup_files/ admin@1.2.3.4:/var/www/example_com/
```

I left the upload running and went to get a coffee only to come back to the following in my terminal:

```
wp-includes/css/wp-embed-template.min.css
wp-includes/css/wp-pointer-rtl.css
wp-includes/css/wp-pointer-rtl.min.css
wp-includes/css/wp-pointer.css
wp-includes/css/wp-pointer.min.css
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (252974 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.2]
```

I tried re-running the same command a few times, just thinking it might be an anomaly due to my slow connection or something out of the ordinary... and to my surprise, I kept noticing very similar lines detailing bytes received. Like this:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (252982 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (252978 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (252962 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (252974 bytes received so far) [sender]
```

That has to be more than a coincidence. The file transfer seems to be getting stopped at exactly 252.9 Kilobytes or so.

What could possibly by the cause of this?

Is there a Debian default limit of 256Kilobytes of traffic over SSH per session or something?

I use rsync all the time from this same Arch Linux local machine to update my websites running Ubuntu without a single error in the few years I have been using this technique.

The second I try to rsync to Debian, this happens.

Comment: What happens if you try `scp` instead? That can fail if the SSH session doesn't give a clean shell without any output, for example. I don't think this is the likely cause, but at least it can rule out a problem with SSH.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a protocol issue, try adding `--protocol=26` or `--protocol=29` to see if it helps.